# How to fix low Lettuce client performance with Redis Cluster (Elasticache)?

Tags: spring-boot, redis, amazon-elasticache, lettuce

Lettuce client performs poorly with Redis Cluster, as bad as 10 times slower compared to single master Redis. I started to notice the issue when number of concurrent requests to the client was around 100. When this issue was observed Redis instances had up to 300 of open connections and it had up to 80k of new connections per minute. When reading keys from the Redis cluster using cli client during performace degradation, it works fine, so it looks like it's a client side issue.

Stack:
Spring Boot 1.5.3
Spring Data Redis 1.5.3
Lettuce 4.4.5
Redis 4.0.10

Comment: Me too facing issue. Did you find solution for this ?

Comment: @Raashith, the issue went away after upgrading to Lettuce 5.x.